# How can user create unique user name

Tags: java, node.js, userid, userinfo

I want to create a unique user name for my users, but this will be not system generated. Users can choose his/her user name.

### DB

MongoDB

#### Ex

Github user name

### Current process

1. sign-up
2. get a verification link on the email
3. go to the link, like `example.com/verify?token=xyz...`

On verify page user can enter a user name, that user name must be unique across the DB.I don't want to keep duplicate user names.

> Many websites have implemented this feature, like Github, GitLab, etc. But, I have explored some web about implementing this feature and I didn't get the desired result.

4. After entering the user name in step 3, the browser will make a `POST` request to the server.
5. Server will then check the DB that if this user name already exists or not, if this already exists then throw an error or process the user name otherwise.

This is working on my local PC, but I am not sure whether this will work when multiple users make a request with the same username within a time interval. Then, in this case, there may be some duplicates in DB.

### case

There are two users A and B wants to create their user name on the system at the same time.

> both are requesting the same user name

1. A: make the request for the user name `u1`
2. Server: check for A's user name is present or not in DB
3. B: make the request for user name `u1`
4. Server: A's user name is not present, save  `u1` as A's user name
5. Server: B's user name is not present, save `u1` as B's user name

You can see, in the end, both users's haveing the same user name.

Is there any way to avoid this??

Comment: You could implement queue where only once A finish his task ___ B can start

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on your Database. If you are using SQL database, you can just add `UNIQUE` constrain to the field, so the database will enforce the uniqueness of an attribute value in the table. The first row will be inserted while another row will fail to insert with an error that the field is not unique.

Speaking of MongoDB, you also have a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/).

Comment: I am already taking the user's email for sign-up, so it should be also unique. I need to take the user name because I would like to create pages based on the user name, not email. So, user email won't be public.

Comment: Just like a blog website instead of `abc.com/user_email@gmail.com/blog/blogId`, i would like to use `abc.com/userName/blog/blogId`.

Comment: Well, there is nothing else I can tell, you need to enforce the uniqueness of the field in your database regardless of the field you want to use.

Comment: That is the problem, MongoDB does not support a unique index on multiple keys, but we can have a unique index on a combination of keys, which is not useful here.

Comment: Well, just create a field where you will be storing a sum/concatenation of multiple fields. :)

And then make that field UNIQUE. 

You will need to handle the updatal of the field manually.

Comment: this would work

Comment: Or, i can use some kind of lock mechanism just like the operating system. So, if one user name is being checked then I'll put that user name in server memory. While the DB operation is pending, if there is any other request is coming for the same user name, then I can check easily in the memory.

Comment: Well, this is a bad idea, because you can hardly scale this solution. Imagine you have more that 1 server, how would you keep that "lock" in sync between multiple servers?

Comment: In case of scaling, we can keep one server for just for checking the unique user name and one for lock.

Answer (score 0):

-> As the above answer suggested have a unique constraint on DB for user name and if the insert didn't happen send an error response stating username already taken also
-> We do not need to wait until the user submits the request, as the user types in the user name, call an API to check if the username already exists, and while calling this cancel the previous request which we haven't got a response back. For example when the user types vi you send a request and it is still in progress but the user has typed vig now before sending the new request with 'vig' data, cancel the previous request. ( Ans simultaneously show the status whether taken or not as you get the responses )

- This improves the user experience.
  -> The cancelling of the requests can be done using cancel tokens in Axios, if you are going with Axios.

For MongoDB:
If you can create an additional unique index based on a combination of fields, can't you use an additional dummy field ( which has the same data for all users), so now your username would stay unique? (I haven't used MongoDB a lot to be sure of this. )

**OR this is mentioned in the Mongo DB documentation , create a proxy collection to maintain this username as a unique key, following the first segment in the below document
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/unique-constraints-on-arbitrary-fields/**

Comment: One thing I can also do is that, create two collections. One for storing all users data along with email, another for storing just user name. So, the schema of user name collection will be something like, `{userName: String, email: String}`. In this way, `email` will be unique in the `users` collection and `userName` will be unique in the user names collection. When I have to retrieve the user name, then I can just look for a user name that corresponds to the current email.

Comment: yes and also in usernames collection add the reference to the collection where you store all the user data too as a parent id, and here make the user name unique

Comment: Yeah, it worked